# Configure UFW for podman on port 443

Tags: docker, nextcloud, podman, ufw

I have deployed nextcloud docker image on my raspberry (ArchLinux ARM) with podman, I have opened 443/tcp port on UFW, but because of UFW nexcloud is unreachable from outside.
If UFW is disabled, everything is working fine. Has anyone already configured UFW for podman on port 443 ?

Comment: It would just be `sudo ufw allow 443`, no? I don't think it would be different for each application. What command did you use to allow that port?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, where the moment `ufw` was enabled no exposed port was reachable from the outside.

`tldr;` what helped me directly was addition of this rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp ! -i cni-podman0 -o cni-podman0 -j ACCEPT
```

however it's one of those things I'm not perfectly sure about re SecOps, so hoping there's someone who can improve on that answer.

Credits go to:
https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2018/12/docker-versus-podman-and-iptables/

where there's way way more description of the problem given, so give it a read too.

Comment: Red Hat's recommendation is here, which is a bit more nuanced than this single rule: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5885821

Answer (score 1):

Beaming in from the future to share an answer that can be achieved purely with ufw commands (which may or may not have been available in 2022).

This works in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and may work elsewhere:

```
ufw route allow in on eth0 out on cni-podman0 to any port 27017
```

If your podman configuration is more complicated than mine you may need to allow traffic `out on` a different network name. To find out where the traffic is trying to go, use:

```
ufw logging on
```

Then attempt your connection while watching with:

```
tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
```

In my case the evidence looked like this:

```
Oct 25 15:11:36 52 kernel: [1379839.607286] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT=cni-podman0 ... more info ...
```

You may wish to turn logging off again to save space.

Answer (score -1):

ufw allow from [sourceIP] to any port [destinationPort]